# Не срабатывает аутентификация на Firebase

Tags: java, android-studio

Подскажите куда копать. 
Посмотрел роликов, посмотрел на гихаб, почитал мануал в AS. Нужно в приложении андроид аутентифицироваться в `Firebase`.

Проект подключил. `google-services.json` содержит правильные ссылки. Зависимости добавлены.

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1
```

Android Studio 3.6.3

В `onCreate` создаю

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Потом при нажатии кнопки запускаю:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
         if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            .....
        }
    } 
});
```

И вот почта и пароль верные, но `task.isSuccessful()` всегда ложь. И всегда исключение дает `FirebaseNetworkException`.

В `firebase` аутентификация по адресу электронной почты и паролю включена.

Куда ещё копать, ничего понять не могу. Всё вроде правильно,  ничего сам не изобретал.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь пермишены

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

И проверь установлены ли на устройстве сервисы Гугла